# Unable to set environment variable in package.json

Tags: javascript, express, environment-variables, package.json

I've tried the following package.json / Express pairs:

1)

```
"config": {
   "PORT": "8000"
}

console.log(Object.keys(process.env).filter(key => key.includes("npm_package_config")))
// returns []
```

2)

```
"scripts": {
   "dev": "cross-env PORT=8000 concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
}

console.log(process.env.PORT)
//returns undefined
```

The `concurrently` command is used to launch and Express app back end along with a React front end.

Comment: So I had this in my devDependencies:  `"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0"` and removing it solved the issue.  I can't remember why I added that originally, but it had something to do with Jest testing.  I guess I need a way to set environment variables after they are altered by that package.